# Importing data from database (mssql) and then passing it to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql

I have a webpage written in asp.net. Recently I've written some javascript for it, looking like this:

```
var data = { "name1":id1, "name2":id2, "name3":id3 }
//some javascript stuff which doesn't change name or id
```

I also have a table with the corresponding name:id values in a mssql database. Is there any way for me to create the data javascript variable from the mssql table automatically?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What you've written in not valid JavaScript. You probably want `var data = { "name1":id1, "name2":id2, "name3":id3 }`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by automatically, but you could Create have a hidden HTML table (With runat="server" attribute) in your HTML form, and load it with a "Select name1,name2,name3 FROM " result on the C# code. This way you could use the loaded table from the JS code